# React-Native get location history

Tags: react-native, geolocation, location

Is there a way to get locations history, or at least have a service to track if user visited certain location.

We want to try to track if the consumer will re-enter the location, even when app is closed.

Starbucks does that (when you're near Starbucks cafe, they send special deals based on that specific Starbucks  cafe)

There is a *Frequent Locations* in iOS, how to get that in [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native)?

Update:
Watching location is not the case, as it requires app to be active

Comment: For that to work I think you have to be watching location of the user all the time and saving the locations user visited in some sort of database or local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use geolocation to listen to a user location. Whenever he enters the location you want, you can trigger a function to do whatever you want.

You can find more details of how to implement it in the official docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: That will not work, we want to get data even when app is closed

Comment: You could implement it while the app is idle. There's also a lib that can do that work for you: https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is **Geofences**. Geofences are an easy way to create an area and check if user has entered, exited and stayed or not. The app works in "terminated" mode as well provided that it has required location permission.

For iOS, you can use the Geolocation framework. I'm hopeful that react-native has a library to use that framework. If not, you can write native code and use it by building native module.

Comment: These seems like good libraries.
https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/wiki/Geofence-Features 
https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation
(I personally haven't used it though.)